# Supervisorctl not respecting my configuration

Tags: supervisord

I have set the following in `/home/david/conf/supervisor.conf`:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/home/david/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/david/tmp/supervisord.log  ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB                    ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10                       ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                            ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/home/david/tmp/supervisord.pid  ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false                           ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                              ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200
childlogdir=/home/david/tmp

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///home/david/tmp/supervisor.sock
```

And started [supervisord](/questions/tagged/supervisord):

```
$ supervisord -c /home/david/conf/supervisor.conf
```

However how come `supervisorctl` still uses the default `http://localhost:9001` as the `serverurl`?

```
$ supervisorctl
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
supervisor>
```

I checked `/home/david/tmp` and the files `supervisord.log` and `supervisord.pid` do exist.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should run `supervisorctl` with `-c` as well. From the documentation (my emphasis):

> The Supervisor configuration file is conventionally named
>   `supervisord.conf`. It is used by both `supervisord` and `supervisorctl`. **If
>   either application is started without the `-c` option** (the option which
>   is used to tell the application the configuration filename
>   explicitly), the application will look for a file named
>   supervisord.conf within the following locations, in the specified
>   order. It will use the first file it finds.
>
> 1. `$CWD/supervisord.conf`
> 2. `$CWD/etc/supervisord.conf`
> 3. `/etc/supervisord.conf`

Comment: If you are able to, move your files to the search directories listed in the snippet, lest you forget to add `-c`, or create an alias in your shell. :)

Comment: I met the same problem and I follow your advise to add `-c /path/to/xxx.conf`, but it came up a new error "unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file". Why ?

Comment: That's another problem entirely. Please post a new question.

Comment: Yes, It was taking up /etc/supervisor.conf instead of the one I have created then supervisorctl stopped working but when I change directory to the place where I have placed my configuration file it works without mentioning the config file explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

- In **MacOS**, use `brew` to install

```sh
 brew install supervisor
```

- Then go to `/usr/local/etc/supervisord.ini` and comment these lines:

```
;[unix_http_server]
;file=/usr/local/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; the path to the socket file
```

and uncomment these lines:

```
[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
port=127.0.0.1:9001        ; ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface
```

- Finally restart the daemon:

```
brew services restart supervisor
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the valid answer above make sure you are putting your config files for the apps you want to monitor under supervisor's config folder as a subfolder called conf.d. This will depend of what method you use to install supervisor, the default package manager or easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

As solution you can make symbolic link to the config file.
Like this for Mac OS:

sudo ln -sv /usr/local/etc/supervisord.ini /etc/supervisord.conf